# .htaccess or something adds additional stuff to the URL. PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just recently started to work with .htaccess on a website i'm working on. Everything works just fine, but when I try to acces the user.php file which is located on the index, I keep getting this url:

> http://lifeline.andornagy.info/user/?url=user

on every other file and place, it works just great.

This is the function with what I call different pages depending on the URL :

```
  public function lifeline() {
        global $templatePath;
        if ( isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] !== 'user'  ) {        
            $url = $_GET['url'];
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url='$url' ");
            if ( !mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
                if ( file_exists($templatePath.'404.php') ) {
                    include_once($templatePath.'404.php');
                } else {
                    include_once('404.php');
                }
            } 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
                if ( $row['type'] === 'post' ) {
                    include_once($templatePath.'post.php');
                } elseif ( $row['type'] === 'page' ) {
                    include_once($templatePath.'page.php');
                }
            }
        } elseif ($_GET['url'] === 'user') {
            include_once($templatePath.'user.php');
        } else {
            include_once($templatePath.'index.php');
        }
    }
```

And this is my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

And I would like if my URL would look like this:

> http://lifeline.andornagy.info/user

Without the /?url=user

Sorry If I sound noobish. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without examining this too closely, the last `RewriteRule` in your .htaccess includes `[R=301]`, making it the only rule capable of "adding" (i.e. redirecting you to) the `/?user=x`. I'd take a closer look at that last rule.

Comment: That rule is for converting spaces to dashes and is not relevant for the question at hand. Unless the user has a space in his username, in which case it does matter. The easiest way to solve that would be to convert spaces to dashes in the script that creates the URL, instead of in Apache (the script is a better place to that anyway)